# Dynamic Web Table : incorrect count of rows in table

Tags: java, selenium

I have code that reads the rows from a web table that consists of multiple pages and prints them. On the last page there are only 2 rows, but the code counts 10 instead (10 is the max rows on a page). When I run it in debug mode and step through, it correctly counts 2 rows. I have no idea why this is happening and would like some help on this.

Here is the web table : https://demo.opencart.com/admin/index.php?route=sale/order&user_token=cf5c87b778476447f8451877fae6af2f

Here is where the rows are counted in my code:

```
//get number of rows
            int rows = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@class='table table-bordered table-hover']//tbody/tr")).size();
            System.out.println("No of Rows: "+rows);
```

Here is all my code:

```
    package mypackage;

import java.time.Duration;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

import io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager;

public class DynamicWebTable {
    static WebDriver driver;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(10));
        
        driver.get("https://demo.opencart.com/admin/");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        
        
        WebElement username = driver.findElement(By.id("input-username"));
        username.clear();
        username.sendKeys("demo");
        
        WebElement password = driver.findElement(By.id("input-password"));
        password.clear();
        password.sendKeys("demo");
        
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[normalize-space()='Login']")).click();
        
        //Close popup
        if(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='modal-content']")).isDisplayed()) {
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='btn-close']")).click();
        }
        
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[normalize-space()='Sales']")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[normalize-space()='Orders']")).click();
        
        //get total no of pages
        String textWithTotalPages = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='col-sm-6 text-end']")).getText();
        int pages = getNumberOfPages(textWithTotalPages);
        System.out.println(pages);
        
        //go through each page
        for(int p = 1; p <= pages; p++) {
            System.out.println("Page no: "+p);
            
            **//get number of rows
            int rows = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@class='table table-bordered table-hover']//tbody/tr")).size();
            System.out.println("No of Rows: "+rows);**
            
            //read rows from page
            for(int r=1; r<=rows; r++) {
                String orderId = retryingFindClick(By.xpath("//table[@class='table table-bordered table-hover']//tbody//tr["+r+"]//td[2]")); 
                String store = retryingFindClick(By.xpath("//table[@class='table table-bordered table-hover']//tbody//tr["+r+"]//td[3]"));
                String customer = retryingFindClick(By.xpath("//table[@class='table table-bordered table-hover']//tbody//tr["+r+"]//td[4]"));
                String status = retryingFindClick(By.xpath("//table[@class='table table-bordered table-hover']//tbody//tr[\"+r+\"]//td[5]"));
                
                System.out.println(orderId+ "  "+store+"  "+customer+"  "+status);
                
            }
            
            //stop when  finished with the last page
            if(p == pages) {
                break;
            }
            
            //click next page
            String nextPage = Integer.toString(p + 1);
            
//          try {
//              driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@class='pagination']//li//a[text()='"+nextPage+"']")).click(); 
//          }catch(ElementClickInterceptedException e) {}
            
            JavascriptExecutor js= (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
            js.executeScript("window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight)");
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@class='pagination']//li//a[text()='"+nextPage+"']")).click(); 
            //waitAndLocate(By.xpath("//ul[@class='pagination']//li//a[text()='"+nextPage+"']")).click();
            
            System.out.println("Clicked page: "+nextPage);
            
        }
        
        
        driver.quit();
    }
        
    //extract number of pages from String 
    public static int getNumberOfPages(String text){
        
        return Integer.valueOf(text.substring(text.indexOf("(")+1, text.indexOf("Pages")-1));
        
    }
    
    public static String retryingFindClick(By by) {
        //boolean result = false;
        String s = null;
        int attempts = 0;
        while(attempts < 2) {
            try {
                s = driver.findElement(by).getText();
                //result = true;
                break;
            } catch(StaleElementReferenceException e) {
            }
            attempts++;
        }
        return s;
    }
    
    public static WebElement waitAndLocate(By by) {
        return new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(2))
                .until(driver -> driver.findElement(by));
    }
        
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote your code to simplify things.

1. I think your main issue was that the script was not waiting properly so when it printed the number of rows for the last page, it was actually printing them for the previous page. The way to prevent this is to use `ExpectedConditions.stalenessOf()`. This takes an existing element on the page and then waits for it to go stale (no longer on the page). I added this at the bottom of every loop to make sure when the > button is clicked to go to the next page, the script pauses until the next page is loaded.
2. I added waits, where needed
3. Instead of getting a count of pages, just loop until there's no > (Next) button
4. Instead of getting a count of rows, just loop through all rows
5. I changed the URL to navigate straight to the sale/order page to save time
6. I removed the implicit wait since you shouldn't mix implicit and explicit waits according to the docs
7. Removed all support methods since they were no longer needed

With all these changes, the code is much shorter, simpler, and works successfully.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    String url = "https://demo.opencart.com/admin/index.php?route=sale/order";
    driver.get(url);

    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("input-username"))).sendKeys("demo");
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("input-password"))).sendKeys("demo");
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("i.fa-key"))).click();

    // loop until last page is reached
    while (true) {
        for (WebElement row : wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.cssSelector("table tr")))) {
            String orderId = row.findElement(By.xpath("./td[2]")).getText();
            String store = row.findElement(By.xpath("./td[3]")).getText();
            String customer = row.findElement(By.xpath("./td[4]")).getText();
            String status = row.findElement(By.xpath("./td[5]")).getText();
            System.out.println(orderId + "  " + store + "  " + customer + "  " + status);
        }

        List<WebElement> nextButton = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[text()='>']"));
        if (nextButton.isEmpty()) {
            break;
        } else {
            nextButton.get(0).click();
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.stalenessOf(nextButton.get(0)));
        }
    }
}
```